# Help me with indefinite integral

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Can You help me with it

$$\int\ \frac{tg^2 x}{ \cos^2x}\ dx$$

I've already tried to decompose tg. But I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: tg^2x=$\tan^2x$, right?

Comment: What is $tg^2 x$ ?

Comment: We have $$\int\tan^2x\sec^2x dx$$ set $\tan x=u$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\tan x$ so $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ so
$$\int\frac{\tan^2x}{\cos^2x} dx =\int f^2(x)f'(x)dx=\frac 1 3 f^3(x)+C$$

Answer (score 3):

If your tg^2x is $\tan^2 x$, then the following is what you want.

$$\int\frac{\tan^2x}{\cos^2x} dx =\frac 13\tan^3x+C.$$

Notice that 
$$(\tan x)^\prime =\frac{1}{\cos^2x}.$$